# UITableView everything top left aligned - error

Tags: ios, uitableview, alignment, swift

I've got a `UITableView` with a few custom prototype cells. Most of the cells contain a simple label that is centered within the cell. There is one cell that contains a `UIButton` with an image which again is centered in the cell.

This loads fine on the simulator and on my iPhone.

**Problem**

If I load a `UIAlertView` popup the whole UITableView content becomes top left aligned (within each cell). The alignment doesn't revert back when the popup is closed.

**Environment**

Built using Swift & Xcode 6 beta 2 for iOS 7+. Testing on iOS 8 beta.

---

Can someone shed some light on what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the cell layout code? Are there any layout warnings sent to the console?